# 'Remind us if we did not give you due credit'

Tags: word-usage

This is what we have for a paper online.

I am not sure whether the word 'due' is used correctly or not.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is OK. Why not?

Comment: [What can an individual do if he/she is not given due credit for his/her work in a research paper?](https://www.quora.com/What-can-an-individual-do-if-he-she-is-not-given-due-credit-for-his-her-work-in-a-research-paper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used correctly. According to Longman Dictionary (5 in the list of meanings of the word "due":http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/due_1),

> **due** 
>   [only before noun] *formal*: **proper or suitable**

"due credit" = "proper/suitable credit"

What your example sentence means is

"Please remind us if we did not give you ***proper/suitable credit for your paper***."